# Android Unit test for Higher-Order functions in ViewModel

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have an android application that I wrote it based on the clean architecture and MVVM for its presentation layer. I have a ViewModel in that its name is `HomeViewModel` ([code on github](https://github.com/abbasiehsan1991/AndroidCleanArchitecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/codenevisha/com/cleanarchitecture/presenter/home/HomeViewModel.kt)). So I want to create a unit test for this ViewModel([Code on github](https://github.com/abbasiehsan1991/AndroidCleanArchitecture/blob/master/app/src/test/java/codenevisha/com/cleanarchitecture/presenter/home/HomeViewModelTest.kt)).

My goal is to create a unit test for `cityWeatherResponse()`. The test that I wrote will fail. But couldn't find the issue.

I really appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Comment: do you have a stack trace ?

Comment: Please post the error that you have. Also, post the relevant code from your Github. Posting GitHub links does not make the question easier to read and understand.